# groovy: filter and extract substring in one go

Tags: regex, jenkins, groovy

I have the piece of code below, in which I filter a list by regex then map(collect) to extract substring from each item.

The question is, can I do it in one go? (without iterating twice...)

```java
//mystring is actually an output produced from: "git -C /my/git/repo --list --remote"
def mystring = """
    origin/branch_a
    origin/branch_b
    origin/branch_mykeyword_w12
    origin/branch_mykeyword_w14
    origin/branch_mykeyword_w16
    """

FIND_BRANCH_PATTERN = ~/.*(mykeyword.+)/
branches = mystring.split("\n").findAll{      //<----- Iteration #1
    // grab all matching branches
    it ==~ FIND_BRANCH_PATTERN
  }.collect {                                 //<----- Iteration #2
    // get the interesting part of the string
    matcher = it =~ FIND_BRANCH_PATTERN
    return matcher[0][1]
} 

return branches.reverse()[0..3]
// return:
// ["branch_mykeyword_w12", "branch_mykeyword_w14", "branch_mykeyword_w16"]
//
// (braches filtered by regex + substring extracted)
```

Comment: Do you want to return all strings after and including `mykeyword`? Then use `def result = (ret =~ FIND_BRANCH_PATTERN).collect { it[1] }`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew IMHO .collect will return a list in same length as original, so I don't see how it will produce the result above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using the `inject` method:

```
def FIND_BRANCH_PATTERN = ~/.*(mykeyword.+)/

def branches = mystring.split("\n").inject([], { acc, branch ->
    def matcher = (branch =~ FIND_BRANCH_PATTERN)

    if (matcher.matches()) {
        acc << matcher[0][1]
    }

    acc
})

assert 3 == branches.size()
```

where `acc` is the accumulated results list.